# Java: try-catch error, must be caught to be thrown

Tags: java, try-catch

I have tried to create a method to load files but it is not working the way it should. Why do I get this error? Is there a problem with my try-catch block?

```
NamnMetod.java:157: error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
   EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
```

This is my code:

```
   public static void hämtaFrånText() {
   EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
   @Override
       public void run() {
          try {
             String aktuellMapp = System.getProperty("user.dir");
             JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(aktuellMapp);
             int resultat = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

             if (resultat != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingen fil valdes!");
                System.exit(0);
             }

                String fil = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                String[] namn = new String[3];
                String output ="";

                BufferedReader inFil = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fil));
                String rad = inFil.readLine();          
                int antal = 0;
                   while(rad != null) {
                       namn[antal] = rad;
                       rad = inFil.readLine();
                       antal++;
                   }
                   inFil.close();           
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e1) {      
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Filen hittades inte!");
            }
            catch(IOException e2) {     
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Det misslyckades");
            }
      }              
   });
}
```

Comment: Something somewhere might throw an `InterruptedException` and you're neither catching it nor declaring that your function may throw one. *Just like the error message says!* Did you even read it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605091/java-bufferedreader-error-with-try-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with the try/catch block in the `run()` method. The problem is with the method that calls `invokeAndWait`... `EventQueue.invokeAndWait()` is declared to throw `InterruptedException`, which is a checked exception... so either you need *another* try/catch block (around the call) or your `hämtaFrånText` method should declare that it can throw `InterruptedException` too.

Comment: I tried to throw InterruptedException in the run() method but  now there is a new error: `NamnMetod.java:160: error: run() in <anonymous NamnMetod$1> cannot implement run() in Runnable
           public void run()throws InterruptedException {
                       ^
  overridden method does not throw InterruptedException
1 error
`

Comment: @samtob: No, it's in the method that *calls* `invokeAndWait` - the `hämtaFrånText` method.

Comment: So I should throw InterruptedException in the hämtaFrånText method? Because, that gives me: `NamnMetod.java:157: error: unreported exception InvocationTargetException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
       EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
`  I then tried to throw InvocationTargetException but it doesn't seem to work... :/

Comment: @samtob: It seems to me that you basically need to read up on what checked exceptions are - they're a core part of Java, and you seem confused by them. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Comment: That is probably the best approach! Thx for all help anyways

Answer (score 0):

As per the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-) (emphasis my own):

> public static void invokeAndWait(Runnable runnable)
>                             throws **InterruptedException**,
>                                    **InvocationTargetException**

The `invokeAndWait` can throw two types of exception. In your method, you do not have a `try-catch` segment to cater with these errors, thus your method must specify that it can potentially throw these exceptions itself because they are not handled internally.

You would need to either:

1. Add `throws InterruptedException` to your method signature OR
2. Have a `try-catch` block which envelopes `EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {...` so that any exceptions can be dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

Defining an anonymous class:

```
new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() { ... }
};
```

is basically a shorthand for defining a local class:

```
class MyAnonymousRunnable implements Runnable {
  @Override public void run() { ... }
}
```

and then creating an instance of that class:

```
new MyAnonymousRunnable();
```

As such, your code could be written as:

```
EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new MyAnonymousRunnable());
```

provided you have a suitable definition of `MyAnonymousRunnable`.
If you did this, you'd get exactly the same compilation error on that line. However, you know how to catch an exception in code without an anonymous class:

```
try {
  EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new MyAnonymousRunnable());
} catch (InterruptedException e) { 
  Thread.currentThread().interrrupt();
  // Do whatever to handle the exception.
}
```

So there is no real difference if you define the class anonymously:

```
try {
  EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() { ... }
  });
} catch (InterruptedException e) { 
  Thread.currentThread().interrrupt();
  // Do whatever to handle the exception.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could envelope your entire `EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){...});` code inside another `try-catch` block like so:

```
public static void hämtaFrånText() {
    try {
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String aktuellMapp = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(aktuellMapp);
                    int resultat = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

                    if (resultat != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingen fil valdes!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }

                    String fil = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                    String[] namn = new String[3];
                    String output = "";

                    BufferedReader inFil = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fil));
                    String rad = inFil.readLine();
                    int antal = 0;

                    while(rad != null) {
                        namn[antal] = rad;
                        rad = inFil.readLine();
                        antal++;
                    }

                    inFil.close();
                } catch(FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filen hittades inte!");
                } catch(IOException e2) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Det misslyckades");
                }
            }
        });
    } catch(InterruptedException e3) {
        // your catch code here
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work. The InterruptedException is not thrown by the same code as the IOExceptions.